# How to run spark-submit with hive libraries

Tags: apache-spark, hive, jar, spark-submit

Currently I am trying to write some data from a dataframe to a Hive table.

I am able to do so in master = local[] & depoy-mode = client. But when I switched to master = yarn & depoy-mode = cluster,  the executor nodes cannot find the required hive libraries.

One option was to provide all the required jars in --jars , but there are quite a few jars and I don't know which specific jars to include.

I am not sure how to solve this:

Are the executor nodes supposed to have all classpath set for hive jars and we don't need to provide the basic hive jars with --jar option?

OR

Is there a way to have hive libraries' classpath added to spark driver jvm so that it distributes them and we don't have to specifically mention each and every jar?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: If the libraries are available on the executor nodes, you can use `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to prepend their location to the executor classpath. There is a corresponding option for the driver classpath. Otherwise, you'll want to use the maven shade plugin to build an uber jar.

Comment: @GaurangShah Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory